# Saving to Firebase storage not possible in an isolate

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have an app feature where the user picks images from his phone and then uploads them to Firebase Storage.
I thought that the upload process should be done in a separate isolate.

I keep getting an exception which I think is related to the Multi Image Picker package.
The exception is:

> E/flutter (12961): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
> Unhandled Exception: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter
> 'defaultBinaryMessenger' was called on null.

When the user presses on the upload button, this method is called:

```
      Future<void> _initIsolate() async {
        ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
    
        receivePort.listen(
          (message) {
            print(message.toString());
          },
          onDone: () => print('Done'),
          onError: (error) => print('$error'),
        );
    
        await compute(
          _function,  // This function is called in the separate isolate
          {
            'sendingPort': receivePort.sendPort,
            'images': images,
          },
        );
      }
```

The _function method is as follows:

```
  static void _function(Map<String, dynamic> parameterMap) async {
    SendPort sendingPort = parameterMap['sendingPort'];
    List<Asset> images = parameterMap['images'];

    List<String> urls = [];
    int index = 0;

    images.forEach(
      (image) async {
        String url = await getDownloadUrl(image);  // a helper method
        urls.add(url);

        sendingPort.send('Image number: $index uploaded');

        index += 1;
      },
    );

    final CollectionReference collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('offers');
    final user = CurrentUser.getCurrentUser();

    await collectionRef.doc(user.uid).set(
      {
        'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        'urls': urls,
      },
    );
  }
```

The helper method _getDownloadUrl is as follows:

```
Future<String> getDownloadUrl(Asset image) async {
  String rannum = Uuid().v1();
  final ByteData byteData = await image.getByteData(); // --> This produces a defaultBinaryMessenger

  final List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

  Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("offers/$rannum");
  UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putData(imageData);
  TaskSnapshot downloadUrl = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
  Future<String> futureUrl = downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL();

  return futureUrl;
}
```

The getByteData method is part of the multi_image_picker package.
The source code is:

```
  Future<ByteData> getByteData({int quality = 100}) async {
    if (quality < 0 || quality > 100) {
      throw new ArgumentError.value(
          quality, 'quality should be in range 0-100');
    }

    Completer completer = new Completer<ByteData>();
    ServicesBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger  // --> Exception here. ServicesBinding.instance is null
        .setMessageHandler(_originalChannel, (ByteData message) async {
      completer.complete(message);
      ServicesBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
          .setMessageHandler(_originalChannel, null);
      return message;
    });

    await MultiImagePicker.requestOriginal(_identifier, quality);
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Why is the ServicesBinding.instance null?
Since this method is working fine without using Isolates, does this have something to do with the isolates?

Comment: called `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`?

Comment: Yes I did. First line in main method

Comment: I've added it to "_function" method which is the method called in the isolate. After a restart of the app, I get an exception: "" Unhandled Exception: Exception: UI actions are only available on root isolate. """

Comment: If I add it to the _initIsolate method which is in my main Isolate, the same previous error occurs

Comment: sorry i missed that: *"I keep getting an exception which I think is related to the Multi Image Picker package. The exception is:"* - does it mean that you are using any UI related code / package in your `Isolate`? i mean: `Multi Image Picker`? if so then you cannot do that - you have to perform UI stuff only in the default, main UI `Isolate`

Comment: I don't think I'm doing an UI stuff in my isolate. I'm doing two things only, the first is uploading images to Firebase Storage and the second is saving the download urls to Firestore. Please check the _initIsolate and _function methods in the code I posted. I can't see any UI code in either methods.

Comment: so call `await image.getByteData()` in the UI `Isolate` and pass data only to your custom `Isolate` - in other words, instead of `'images': images,` pass only raw data needed for upload

Comment: I have fallen into an interesting rabbit hole. As you suggested, I passed the raw data to the isolate instead of the actual images. In order to do I had to separate the getDownloadUrl method into two, one for transforming to raw data, the other for upload to Storage. Then I got an error `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()`. So I called initializeApp() in the Isolate function `_function`. Then got a new exception `Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.`

Comment: A message associated with the last exception is:  `If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.`  I found this odd, but went ahead and called it in the isolate method `_function`. Then I got an exception `Unhandled Exception: Exception: UI actions are only available on root isolate.`

Comment: hmm, so it seems that cannot use your firebase storage in the isolate... did you have any serious problems when using it from main ui isolate?

Comment: Yes. It's just very very slow. I'm collecting the futures in a list of futures. Then wait for them to finish in a FutureBuilder  ( `future: Future.wait(futureList)` ). I used a FutureBuilder to show the user the loading indicator. It's the first computation in my app that takes a long long time. It's weird.

Comment: so maybe use `Future.forEach` that completes the futures one by one and not `Future.wait` which completes them all at once?

Comment: but honestly you should use `StreamBuilder`, not `FutureBuilder` - for example if you have 10 files to upload the builder should be triggered 10 times, am i right? with `FutureBuilder` its gonna be run only when all the files are uploaded

Comment: This is a very interesting suggestion. It will take a rewrite of all my methods, but I think I can do it. As far as I understand it, I think the builder of `FutureBuilder` triggers once. Since it's taking a list of futures and waiting for all of them to end.

Comment: it shouldnt be that hard, use `Stream.fromIterable` and call `asyncMap` on it - the method used by `asyncMap` should upload one file

Comment: I'm setting the futures as `futureList = images.map((image) => getDownloadUrl(image)).toList();`  Your comment made me rethink this line. Now it smells funny. It might be what's causing the issue. I can't know for certain now, until I rewrite my methods

Comment: `Stream.fromIterable(images).asyncMap(getDownloadUrl)` thats all - use that stream with `StreamBuilder` and the `builder` will be called each time one file is uploaded

Comment: I got a weird bug I'm still trying to manage where it uploads one image less than the total number of images (4 out 5 images or 9 out of images). This issue aside, the upload can be interrupted by UI action. Also, I feel it takes longer time than the `Future.wait` for some reason. Using the `FutureBuilder` had the slight advantage of showing the progress indicator while the upload process was going on.

Comment: It looks like the best solution was the isolate one, but looks like isolates and Firebase storage do not play well with each other.

Comment: with `Future.wait` and `FutureBuilder` you cannot tell the progress - you only have 0/1 indicator - with `StreamBuilder` you can see 0, 1, 2, 3 ... progress - personally i would prefer to know how many files were uploaded so far

Comment: and if it is not working what do you see on the logs if you call `Stream.fromIterable(images).asyncMap(getDownloadUrl).listen(print);` ?

Comment: I strongly agree with what you said about the progress. An incremental progress indicator is way better than a 0/1. Can I get show the user this incremental progress? Since I'm inside the builder of the `StreamBuilder`, I don't have to any indices I can use.